# Exibir imagem a ser carregada PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Olá gostaria de saber como exibir uma imagem que está para ser carregada em um `INPUT FILE`

Por exemplo, quando o usuário clicar para carregar a imagem e após seleciona-la como faço para exibir um Preview da imagem antes do submit do formulário?

Comment: Estude como carregar arquivos utilizando a File API. É pré-requisito ter conhecimento em Javascript para implementar este tipo de funcionalidade.

Answer (score 2):

Esta abordagem resolve este problema de maneira simples, usando apenas jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<input id="imgInput" type="file">
<script>
$("#imgInput").change(function(){
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#view-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
</script>

<img id="view-img" src="default.jpg">
```

Comment: Pode explicar um pouco o código? Ele vai exibir a imagem pelo caminho do arquivo na maquina do usuário ou faz um upload paralelo?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader e http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Comment: Ele não faz upload, apenas mostra a imagem em tempo de execução, direto da máquina. Fazer o upload é outra história.